# how to redirect react router v6 after login?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, router

Doesn't work redirect react-router v6 when I use location and history but the history push doesn't work.

```
const signInWithGoogle = (location, history) => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        history.push(location?.state?.from || '/')
        const user = result.user;
        saveUsers(user.email, user.displayName, 'PUT')

        setUser(user)

        setAuthError('')
      }).catch((error) => {
        setAuthError(error.message)

      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In react-router v6, you should use `useNavigate` instead of `useHistory`.
If I could just modify that part of this code, it would look like this:

```
const signInWithGoogle = (location, navigate) => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        // change
        navigate(location?.state?.from || '/')
        const user = result.user;
        saveUsers(user.email, user.displayName, 'PUT')

        setUser(user)

        setAuthError('')
      }).catch((error) => {
        setAuthError(error.message)

      })
  }
```

In addition, the functions of `useHistory` in `useNavigate` have been changed as follows.

```
// history.push('/')
navigate('/')
// history.replace('/')
navigate('/', {replace:true})
```